# How to access http session and retrieve requested dbms queries in IIS in real time?

Tags: database, iis, httpsession

I need retrieve all the dbms queries submitted in http session in real time in order to let it execute or not in IIS. Is it possible to do that? what steps I should use?

Comment: What is the definition of "dbms queries" in this question? IIS only knows an HTTP request comes, so it has no idea whether your web application performs any database queries once the request is passed on. Thus, you have the responsibility to surface such queries to HTTP level (specific URLs, and/or specific verbs, and/or specific headers for instance) or you should do such inside your web application.

Comment: Thank for your explanation. Then how could I access HTTP requests? which language should I use for that? If possible please let me know detailed explanation. Thank you in advance